# Do I need to boil flax seed egg substitute?

Tags: baking, vegan, flax

Most recipes I've seen for flax “eggs” simply say to mix 1 tbsp of ground flax seed with 3 tbsp of water and chill, but I read a recipe (I think it was for vegan cookies) that said to boil the mixture before chilling.

Does this improve the chemistry of the egg substitute in any way?

Comment: I don't know if it improves things, but I've just let it sit and it's worked fine.  I don't tend to refrigerate unless I'm mixing up a large batch (to make it easier when baking many types of christmas cookies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heating the water will speed up absorption. The question is by how much and if it’s worth the extra time?
I have made many recipes with flax as an egg substitute. I don’t ever recall boiling the water. I can’t think of any of them that didn’t turn out as intended. 
Do you have any links for the recipes that recommend this?

Comment: Nope. I can't seem to find it. Your experience matches mine though, so I'll probably accept this answer. Any references for the claim about absorption?